# Running mutate is not updating my dataset

Tags: r

I am running the following code:

```
brfss2013 <- brfss2013 %>%
  mutate(smokers9900 = ifelse( (smoke100 == "Yes" & smokday2 == "Everyday") & (chcocncr == "Yes" | chccopd1 == "Yes"), "Yes", "No"))
```

Where smoke100, smokday2, chcocncr, chccopd1 are all column names in table brfss2013 and "Yes"/"No" are valid values for those features.

I am expecting another column getting added to the table brfss2013, but that is not happening. What is wrong?

First row from my table:

Alabama
January
1092013
January
9
2013
Completed interview
2013000580
2013000580
Yes
Yes
NA
Yes
Not a cellular phone
NA
2
1
1
Fair
30
29
30
Yes
Yes, only one
No
Within past year
NA
Yes
Yes
Yes
Within past year
Yes
No
NA
No
Yes
Yes
No
No
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
No
Divorced
0
College 4 years or more (College graduate)
Retired
Less than $75,000
250
507
Yes
2 residential telephone numbers
Yes
10
Yes
Own
Female
NA
Yes
Yes
No
No
Yes
No
Yes
Yes
Not at all
NA
10 years or more
Not at all
201
2
0
2
304
104
303
310
303
NA
No
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
0
Yes
Yes
A lot
7
Always
No
NA
No, did not receive any tetanus since 2005
Yes
No

EDIT ---

Just realised that column is indeed getting added. However, I cannot see it when I View the table. WOuld be glad if someone can answer why that is happening.

Comment: can you give a reproducible sample of `brfss2013`?

Comment: @Sotos Not sure what you mean by "reproducible" sample, but I can paste a row of information here. Shall I do that? Not sure how I can nicely put up a few rows from a table with many columns over here though.

Comment: Just edit your question and add the result of `dput(head(brfss2013))`

Comment: @Sotos I tried dput, but the output is too large and doesn't fit in console output. Searched how I can increase console output buffer, but that didn't give any answers. `source("file.txt", echo=T)` didn't help.

Comment: @Sotos I can see how the first row might now help.

Comment: Even so, make it reproducible so we can use it `dput(head(brfss2013, 1))` or include only the columns of interest

Comment: @Sotos Even `dput(head(brfss2013, 1))` was too large an output to fit inside the console.

Comment: @Sotos I ran colnames() and saw that the column is actually getting added, however, when I cannot see it in the upper right table viewer. What do you think is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The View and some others utils of RStudio have a limit on the number of columns that they display.